# Minimum Fixed Monthly Payment Result is Wrong

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

Write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months. By a fixed monthly payment, we mean a single number which does not change each month, but instead is a constant amount that will be paid each month.

The following variables contain values as described below:

balance - the outstanding balance on the credit card

annualInterestRate - annual interest rate as a decimal

Assume that the interest is compounded monthly according to the balance at the end of the month (after the payment for that month is made). The monthly payment must be a multiple of $10 and is the same for all months. Notice that it is possible for the balance to become negative using this payment scheme, which is okay. A summary of the required math is found below:

Monthly interest rate = (Annual interest rate) / 12.0

Monthly unpaid balance = (Previous balance) - (Minimum monthly payment)

Updated balance each month = (Monthly unpaid balance) + (Monthly interest rate x Monthly unpaid balance)

=================================================

Test Case 1:

Enter your balance: 3329

Enter your Annual Interest Rate: 0.2

Lowest Payment: $310

Test Case 2:

Enter your balance: 4773

Enter your Annual Interest Rate: 0.2

Lowest Payment: $440

Test Case 3:

Enter your balance: 3926

Enter your Annual Interest Rate: 0.2

Lowest Payment: $360

Start with $10 payments per month and calculate whether the balance will be paid off in a year this way (be sure to take into account the interest accrued each month - this means 10 * 12 won't work).If $10 monthly payments are insufficient to pay off the debt within a year, increase the monthly payment by $10 and repeat.

This is what I have and I cant get the program to equal the lowest payment in the test cases when I put in the balance and interest rate. I also have to use the nested loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MinPayment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your balance: ");
        double balance = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter your Annual Interest Rate: ");
        double rate = input.nextDouble();
        double i = 1;
        rate = rate / 12.0; 
        double payment = 0;
        while (i <= 12) {
            i++;
            balance = balance + (rate * balance);
            while (balance >= 0) {
                payment += 10;
                balance = balance - payment;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Lowest Payment: $%.0f", payment);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while ((balance > 0) {` this line won't compile.

Comment: What does "I cant get the program to work with the test cases?" mean? What do you expect your code to do that it's not doing?

Comment: I have to get the program to equal the lowest payment in the test cases when I put in the balance and annual interest rate. @MarsAtomic

Comment: for future reference, the really smart people on SO tend to be the pickiest about how you form your question. you will get really helpful and quick responses if you include what your problem is exactly, what you have tried, and a descriptive title, about you problem with the code, not your specific problem. so something like, nested loop not returning expected value

Answer (score 0):

```
double monthlyRate = annualRate / 12.0; 
double monthlyUnpaidBalance;
double prevBalance=balance;
double payment=10;
boolean minPaymentReached=false;

while(true)
{

   prevBalance=balance;

    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {

    monthlyUnpaidBalance=prevBalance-payment; 

        if(monthlyUnpaidBalance<=0)
        {
        minPaymentReached=true;
        break;
        }
        prevBalance=monthlyUnpaidBalance+(monthlyRate*monthlyUnpaidBalance);
    }

    if(minPaymentReached)
    {
    break;
    }
    payment=payment+10;

}
```

by setting temporary variables equal to the balance we preserve the initial value and are able to set the 'prevBalance' back to balance at the beginning of the while(true) loop

Comment: I believe the ((balance>0) is an answer...maybe not the one hes looking for depending on the op's response. But he asked why it want working...it definitely will not work with that extra paren. I repeated it because this is obviously some student or something just learning, just saying it is a compilation error will probably not help him. i told him what was wrong.

Comment: Oh, did not notice as first as you wrote `paren` ... Edited your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I often forget that the short hand i use is not understood by everyone...although a quick Google search shows that paren is a widely used abbreviation, especially for a single parenthesis.

Comment: I'm using notepad++ for an Intro to Java Programming course. I fixed the compilation error and got 260 as the lowest payment for the first test case. The instructor wants all the test cases to work and for there to be a nested loop in the program.

Comment: did he give you the logic to figure out a minimum payment? there are a lot of different approaches, i think your logic is flawed, not the implementation. my minimum payment is interest + 1% of balance on one of my cards just as an example. And netbeans is free. Im all for learning how to do it the hard way, but an IDE makes learning the simple stuff easy so you can focus on the bigger issues later.

Comment: He told me to do this:Start with $10 payments per month and calculate whether the balance will be paid off in a year this way (be sure to take into account the interest accrued each month - this means 10 * 12 won't work).
If $10 monthly payments are insufficient to pay off the debt within a year, increase the monthly payment by $10 and repeat.Think hard about how the program will know when it has found a good minimum monthly payment value.

Comment: Also this: If there is a balance remaining at the end of the year, how could we write code that would reset the balance to the initial balance, increase the payment by $10, and try again (using the same code!) to compute the balance at the end of the year, to see if this new payment value is large enough.

Comment: to answer your last question, that inner while should be an if(balance>0), you could create a temporary variable to store balance while you perform operations on it, then set equal to original balance if you ever need to.

Comment: I cant get rid of the while statement because he wanted us to use a nested loop for the problem.

Comment: use a while(true) loop to keep it in infinite loop while you increment the payment and break the loop when payment is reached

Comment: When I did that, it didn't give me an answer.

Comment: you have to make sure that the condition set to break out of the loop is able to be set to true, you were stuck in an infinite loop so it never output the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the `payment` variable, that gets increased by 10, and then again subtracted from the balance.

```
int i = 1; // Make it an int. Name it 'month'.
rate /= 12.0; 
double payment = 0; // totalPayment
final double SINGLE_PAYMENT = 10;
while (i <= 12) {
    i++;
    balance += rate * balance; 
    if (balance >= SINGLE_PAYMENT) { // Not while, this month only, not 0
        payment += SINGLE_PAYMENT;
        balance -= SINGLE_PAYMENT;
    }
}
```

The rate logic is for you to consider.

Comment: the problem is that he needs a nested loop.